# Disable AJAX Caching

Tags: ajax

I am in a bit of a pickle right now. I am building a web page that will get data from a CGI backend. I have no control over the CGI backend, nor the server (so no mod_headers or mod_expires). Also, because of the parameters to the script, I cannot append a unique value (like '&089u0af0d98) to each request. The requests are AJAX using the XmlHttpRequest object. I have tried to set the 'If-Modified-Since' and 'Cache-Control' request headers unsuccessfully. Does anybody have any other ideas for how I can prevent the AJAX response from being cached by the browser?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can send random parameters using POST, while sending the important vars using GET if you need to.

If you have problems with IE, I know that sending something with POST makes it to stop caching server responses

Answer (score 12):

I use this javascript function ( which in turn uses jquery.ajax function )
the cache: false would do the trick.
This works perfectly for me , may be you can give it a try

```
    function ajax_call(urlString)
    {
        ret_val="";
        $.ajax
        (
            {
                type: "GET",
                url: urlString,
                async:false,
                cache:false,
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(msg)
                {
                    ret_val=msg;
                },
                error:function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError)
                {
                    ret_val=xhr.readyState;
                    alert("status=" +xhr.status);
                }
            }
        );
        return ret_val;
    }
```

Comment: As I mentioned to David, jQuery appends a unique value to my URL string, which is something that doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 7):

I used `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });` somewhere in my base html-page (default.aspx) in a non-frequent web-system and it worked fine. No pain-in-the-neck caching problems anymore.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this today, and found that if you want to keep to using get, you can add a hidden form element to the page and have JS set it's value to the current timestamp before submitting the query to ajax.

I add a form element something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ie_sucks" id="ie_sucks", value="1" />
```

Then, in the function to submit the form via AJAX I set this hidden input to the current timestamp with something like this:

```
$('#ie_sucks').val(new Date().getTime());
```

The above code uses JQuery, so in pure JS it would be something like:

```
document.getElementById('ie_sucks').value = new Date().getTime();
```

This is not a pretty solution, but it does work.

Answer (score 1):

I know jQuery's `.ajax()` call has a parameter called 'cache' which, if set to false, [will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).  It's probably worth [checking the jQuery source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.js) to see how they do it.

(I'm checking it now and will update if I find anything, but posting this answer early in case you or anybody else has better luck finding it.)

Comment: I have messed with that before. It works by appending a unique value to the end of the URL and data parameters. Unfortunately, the idiot that wrote the script did it in such a way that I can't do that.