# Pressing browser back button makes use unwanted cached answered of ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, caching

On my EmberJS App Ajax requests are coming from cache only when I hit the back button.

Scenario is:

- I go to a list
- I add an item (item A)
- I open an item (this will load a new page, no ajax here)
- I press back
- The list is displayed without item A
- I hit refresh
- The list is displayed with item A

The server does not send any headers to cache the answer.

How can I prevent the browser to get answer from cache after pressing back button?

Comment: Do you want to sisable the back button.

Comment: No, I want to disable the cache :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216234/disable-ajax-caching#6216325

Comment: I thought there would be a nicer way to do this. The server does not even tell to cache the answer!

Comment: A nicer way? Javascript and webdesign has the most ugly code I've ever seen. It's even more ugly than assembly.