# jQuery AJAX issue IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have the following code that works perfectly across all major browsers except IE8.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://APPSECRET:APPKEY@my.site.com/admin/products.json',
        cache: false, 
        timeout: 15000,
        success: function(jsonp, status, XMLHttpReq){
            callback(jsonp);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Error');
        },
        dataType: 'jsonp'
    });
```

When I run it in IE 8 the error function is triggered and I receive the alert. I have lookup up other solutions on here and even set the cache to false which still doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

or

```
$.ajax({
  cache: false,
  //other options...
});
```

or

Appends a timestamp to the querystring

I think this question duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/a/4303862/169469