# IE 9, IE 8 Comp error with jCryption jQuery plugin - not generating keypair due to caching

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, caching, internet-explorer-9, jcryption

I discovered an issue with Internet Explorer 9 and Internet Explorer 8 Comp (so far) with the jQuery plugin, jCryption.  Calling the page the first time works fine in said IE version.  Subsequent calls to the page result in only the *handshake* being called, while *keypair generation* is ignored.  The problem is how these version of IE handle caching.

I looked at the source code of jCryption and here is the set of code which calls *keypair generation*:

```
/**
* Gets the data from the specified url, and converts it into a RSA keypair
* @param {string} url The URL to contact
* @param {string} data The JSON data
*/
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
                var keys = new jCryptionKeyPair(data.e, data.n, data.maxdigits);
                if($.isFunction(callback)) {
                        callback.call(this, keys);
                }
        });
```

I changed it's request from GET to POST, which effectively disables caching of this request.

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
                         var keys = new jCryptionKeyPair(data.e, data.n, data.maxdigits);
                         if ($.isFunction(callback)) {
                                 callback.call(this, keys);
                         }
                 }
        });
```

The *handshake* code is similar, in that it also makes a jQuery Ajax POST request.

Comment: IE caches the results of AJAX calls. Try adding cache:false to the [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) calls. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303829/how-to-prevent-jquery-ajax-caching-in-internet-explorer

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I have tried using Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store and it did not work.  Setting cache: false to the $.ajax call works, but I don't feel it's the most elegant, clean solution.  The author of the jCryption uses an $.ajax call for the *handshake*.  So, I modeled the above solution after his call.