# prevent IE from caching data with jaydata requests

Tags: internet-explorer, caching, jaydata

How is it possible to prevent IE from caching data with jaydata requests?

I've read this post:
[How to prevent a jQuery Ajax request from caching in Internet Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303829/how-to-prevent-a-jquery-ajax-request-from-caching-in-internet-explorer)
and this article:
http://www.greenvilleweb.us/how-to-web-design/problem-with-ie-9-caching-ajax-get-request/

the solution I found with jQuery is to set {cache:false}. But How can I do it with a jaydata request?

```
$data.initService(url)
  .then(function(db) {
    db.table ....
```

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I modified my function so that it accept a parameter "time". That allow me to have have the same behavior as jQuery with {cache: false}. This behavior is explained in the links above. This fix my issue:

```
$data.initService(url)
  .then(time, function(db) {
    db.table ....
```