# sometimes ajax works & sometime not & click on row function is also not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, datatables

can we write two ajax success function on same page because sometimes its work sometime not 
doajaxpost function is to load data in 2nd dropdown list when 1st dropdown list onchange function call by using ajax
and searching function is to load data in table by using ajax
but it sometime get execute properly sometimes not showing any result

```
 function doAjaxPost(instituteId) {

        alert(instituteId);
        // get the form values  
        /* var name = $('#name').val();
        var education = $('#education').val(); */
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "/paymentGateway/merchant",
            dataType : "json",
            data : "institutionId=" + instituteId,
            success : function(data) {
                // we have the response  
                alert(data + "hiee");
                var $merchantId = $('#merchant');

                $merchantId.find('option').remove();
                $("#merchant").append("<option value='ALL'>ALL</option>");
                $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                    $('<option>').val(value.merchantId).text(value.merchantId)
                            .appendTo($merchantId);
                });

            },
            error : function(e) {
                alert('Error: ' + e);
            }
        });
    }

    function searching() {
        // get the form values  
        var institutionId = $('#instiuteId').val();
        var merchantId = $('#merchant').val();
        var userType = $('#userType').val();
        var userStatus = $('#userStatus').val();
        var userId = $('#userId').val();

        alert("insti=" + institutionId + "mecrhant=" + merchantId + "usertyep="
                + userType + "users=" + userStatus + "userid=" + userId);
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "/paymentGateway/searching",
            dataType : "json",
            data : {
                institutionId : institutionId,
                merchantId : merchantId,
                userId : userId,
                userStatus : userStatus,
                userType : userType
            },
            success : function(data) {
                // we have the response  
                alert(data);
                /*  var $merchantId = $('#dynamictable');
                   $merchantId.find('table').remove(); 
                 $('#dynamictable').append('<table></table>');
                 var table = $('#dynamictable').children();  */

                $("#tablenew tbody tr:has(td)").remove();

                $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                    /*        alert(value.institutionId);  */
                    $('#tablenew tbody:last').append(
                            "<tr><td>" + value.userId + "</td><td>"
                                    + value.firstName + "</td><td>"
                                    + value.userStatus + "</td><td>"
                                    + value.userType + "</td><td>"
                                    + value.userAddedBy + "</td><td>"
                                    + value.userRegisteredDateTime
                                    + "</td><td>" + value.recordLastUpdatedBy
                                    + "</td><td>" + value.recordLastUpdatedTime
                                    + "</td></tr>");
                });

            },
            error : function(e) {
                alert('Error: ' + e);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be a caching issue, try to setup

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

See 
[How to prevent a jQuery Ajax request from caching in Internet Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303829/how-to-prevent-a-jquery-ajax-request-from-caching-in-internet-explorer)

Comment: POST requests aren't cached.

Comment: You are right, but I can't see any obvious issue in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. You'll have to use the class instead of ID to make it work. Use $(".merchant") to replace $("#merchant"), and update 'merchant' to be a class.