# Content not updating, because of cache

Tags: jquery, ajax, file, caching

Good evening everyone!
So basically i take the data from a file with ajax and put it in HTML div. The problem here is if i change anything in the file, then save it and reload my page, the content in the HTML is not updated, but is still the same. However when i set in Mozilla cache to 0 it updates the information.

```
     $.ajax({
        url: "./Tasks/2014/10.09.2014/Task_100914.txt",
        async: true,
        cashe: false,
        success: function (data){
        $('#task').text(data); 

        pageExecute.fileContents = data;            
        }
    });
```

I tried with "cashe: false", but it does not work.

Comment: If this is the real code, you have spelled "cache" wrongly.

Comment: There is no real solution, and yes, it's a real problem. I think the usual workaround is to add a dummy text in the form of `?x=(random)` to the end of the url (where (random) is some random number that changes every time). By the way, it's not evening for everyone!

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303829/how-to-prevent-a-jquery-ajax-request-from-caching-in-internet-explorer

Comment: @Kolban correct +1,  Change  `cashe: false,` to `cache: false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change:

```
cashe: false,
```

To:

```
cache: false,
```

Follow [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
**cache (default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp')**
`Type: Boolean`
If set to `false`, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser. Note: Setting cache to false will only work correctly with `HEAD` and `GET` requests. It works by appending `"_={timestamp}"` to the `GET` parameters. The parameter is not needed for other types of requests, except in IE8 when a `POST` is made to a URL that has already been requested by a `GET`.

Comment: Hah, so awkward ... such a stupid mistake. Thank you now it works fine. :)