# Disable cache on php and html with AJAX

Tags: php, html, caching

I use AJAX for my website and my website some part load after document is ready by AJAX and those parts are dynamic.

Example one part: Hello #USERNAME# this is different for every ID, When i log in to first ID show my username but when log in to second ID this name do not change and show first ID username.

I disabled cache in all PHP pages by above code:

```
<?php 
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
```

But cache is not disabled.

Comment: PRO TIP: To keep from caching AJAX requests add a pseudo timestamp to the end of the URL you request.

Comment: An example of what Jay Blanchard is saying above, is to request the page like this: 'http://yoursite.com/ajax_script.php?t=1152014105753' where the string of numbers is the current date/time down to the second. This will skip caching and treat it like a new file to your browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this question is a little bit of a duplicate. However, if you want to ensure that caching does not happen on ajax calls, you can append a timestamp to the end of the URL you are hitting.

Example in your JavaScript AJAX prep:

```
var time_stamp = new Date().getTime();
var myurl = "url_here.php?timestamp=" + time_stamp;
jQuery.get(myurl, /* more parameters */);
/* other relevant code */
```

Here are some other sources from Google:

- [How to prevent a jQuery Ajax request from caching in Internet Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303829/how-to-prevent-a-jquery-ajax-request-from-caching-in-internet-explorer)
- http://hungred.com/how-to/tutorial-stop-caching-jquery-javascript/
- http://viralpatel.net/blogs/ajax-cache-problem-in-ie/
- [Stop jQuery .load response from being cached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168963/stop-jquery-load-response-from-being-cached)

Another thing to consider is that it might not be a caching issue. Are you properly clearing any sessions/cookies? (If you are using them)