# How to remove Microsoft Edge's cache using PHP or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, microsoft-edge

I've currently started on a project including AJAX, and I ran into a problem. When using Microsoft Edge (and Internet Explorer) it won't update data, unless I close the entire page and open it again, or if I open my PHP file, from which I send data through AJAX.

Does anyone no how to solve this issue using PHP and/or Javascript?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What caching header(s) is your server sending with the response?

Comment: @KevinB It just keeps sending the excact same data through the Ajax, though in Chrome and Firefox the data gets updated, and I'm not exactly bit 99% it's the cache

Comment: What caching header(s) is your server sending with the response?

Comment: I'm not sure I now what you mean, sry

Comment: When you send an ajax request to the server, it responds with a response. That response has headers. We need to see said headers.

Comment: But how do I do that exactly? (Sorry, I thought I knew a lot about this, but apparently not)

Comment: Press F12 and go to the network tab, click on the request, information will be on the right

Comment: Remote Address:[::1]:80
Request URL:http://localhost/games/dbrsp/players.php?server=qxspn
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK - General tap, this is from Chrome

Comment: I'm looking for the information in the "Response Headers" section

Comment: Connection:Keep-Alive  
Content-Length:305  
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8  
Date:Thu, 08 Oct 2015 17:58:52 GMT  
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100  
Server:Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1m PHP/5.6.11  
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.6.11   - Might be worth mentioning that it's a xampp server running locally

Comment: Looks like no caching headers at all. If you want this request to not be cached, you shoudl have php or xampp return caching headers that specify not to  cache. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers Ie is likely caching by default due to there beign no instructions of doing otherwise.

Comment: So in this case, I should find some code fitting into my JS Ajax code?

Comment: No, it's all server-side.

Comment: There's very little you can do client-side, other than using the cache: false option in the ajax request, but the no cache header is a far better solution.

Comment: Kinda noticed, thank you very much, working just fine! Please write an answer, just anything, and I'll accept it :)

Comment: you can find answer here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36435567/microsoft-edge-caching-ajax-requests/42082570#42082570

Comment: @S.MohamedMahdiAhmadianzadeh A little late, but useful, thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A "quick fix" would be to use the cache: false option of the $.ajax method, but this really isn't the right way to solve this problem if you have control of the server. Instead, you shoudl have php return a no-cache header on services you don't want cached, and a cache header on services you do want cached.

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
header("Expires: 0"); // Proxies.
```

The above code was taken from BalusC's answer over here: [How to control web page caching, across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers)

Otherwise, you should have an htaccess that specifies which files should be cached such as static assets that don't change often (.html, .js, .css, etc)

Answer (score -1):

You can check some of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011605/clear-the-cache-in-javascript). I don't think the browser will allow you to clear the cache directly through javascript. There are workarounds that may be able to solve your problem, though.