# Same data when i send multiple ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I try to send multiple requests on the same url. I send users.length requests to the server because i need to ban all those users are in this array. The problem is that this code returns me always the same data. I know that i must use promises but i can't convert this code.

```
for(i = 0; i<selected_users.length; i++)
{
  $.post(webRoot + "ban-user",
  {
    "user-id" : selected_users[i],
    "action-type" : action_type
  },
  function(data,status){
    if(status == "success")
    {
      alert(data);
    }
  }
 });
}
```

Comment: *this code returns me always the same data*  May be because the server is responding with the same data?

Comment: It might be helpful to have a description of what is being sent over the network, or at least what values are supplied to each `$.post` call. As written, this code looks like it will send one request for each member of `selected_users`. If that's not what's happening, you may not be showing the relevant parts of the code. If that *is* what is happening, then perhaps your server is to blame -- it's sending back the same results for different inputs.

Comment: Your code has an extra `}` before the `);`

Comment: As the others said you need to provide more information. What is your server side code?

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

this will prevent caching.

check [this answer in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303829/how-to-prevent-a-jquery-ajax-request-from-caching-in-internet-explorer)